# How to create a new column for calculate the mean of the three existing columns?

Tags: r, mean, spatial

I have spatial data (polygons) and I want to create a mean based on the three columns. I think I must create a new column to calculate the mean based on the three  existing columns.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should add a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), so it'll be a lot easier to help you. Use `sf` package to read your polygons. Then you can use `mutate` from `dplyr`.

Comment: See `?rowMeans`.

Comment: library(raster)
library (rgdal)
library (sf)
balprof <- readOGR("/home/vlad/Documents/vldZ/Master/Baltati/Baltati/Vectori/Prof_Baltati.shp") # a  polygon shape with   36 columns . So I  have 4  columns of  pH values and  want to  create a  column of  the  mean of the  ph